# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role , Spring

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to get info from an API in Spring, but it gives me an error because one of the fields is a Set. How to get a json with all of the info? If i use JsonIgnore, it won't give me the set i need, right?

My class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "saloon")
public class Saloon implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "saloon")
    private Set<Service> services;


...
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection valued attributes are by default lazily-fetched. One easy solutio is to changing it to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "saloon", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

But that might cause severe performance issues in various cases.

To get to an optimal solution, you need to analyze your design, ie how you are using this property in your code.

You can take a look at [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html).